# Mantenedor de formulas en SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Escribo para solicitar vuestra orientación por favor.

Debo almacenar en una tabla de una BD en `SQL Server`, las formulas que usaré en un sistema.

EJ TABLA FORMULAS :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para luego en mi programación (`PHP`, `JS`, etc.) use esas formulas solo reemplazando los campos de la formula, esto con el fin de no tener que programar cada una de las formulas, si no que pueda almacenarlas en la base de datos.

No se me ocurre como hacer esto, sería genial me ayudaran con alguna idea de un caso similar.

Comment: vas a usar luego eval para ejecutar una sentencia que no existe? eval no es una buena idea, nunca... como ejecutarias luego de hacer el reemplazo (si fuera posible) la consulta que queres? Si esto fuera comun, habria una libreria que lo hace. Que es lo que queres ahorrar?

Comment: ¿Cómo planeas validar las fórmulas? ¿Cómo defines de que tabla viene cada columna? La idea puede sonar bien, pero tiene muchas complicaciones. La peor de todas es como prevenir la inyección de SQL.